# can't figure out why Im getting System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException for Excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0, oledb

```
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    // Show the dialog and get result.
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        labelFilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + labelFilePath.Text.Trim() + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
        using (var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)) 
        { 
            conn.Open(); 
            try
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select * From [Sheet1]";
                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int firstNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("First Name");
                        int lastNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("Last Name");
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("First Name: {0}, Last Name: {1}", reader.GetString(firstNameOrdinal), reader.GetString(lastNameOrdinal));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException odbe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(odbe.Errors.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(odbe.Message.ToString());
            }
        } 

    }
    Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use only.

}
```

I get the error at `OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Here is the output

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll System.Data.OleDb.OleDbErrorCollection The
>   Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1'. 
>   Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path
>   name correctly. OK

Comment: Can we see exception details?

Comment: You need to show the OleDbException.Message property and possibly the innerException (and it's Message property).

Comment: Is the file already open in an instance of excel or another DB connection (i.e. SSMS)??

Comment: I don't have the file open. Excel is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the following line (note the $):

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";
```

In this case you are selecting everything from the sheet, however this notation extends to select named ranges as follows:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From [Sheet1$NamedRange]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: I have had oledb exceptions in Excel drivers when i was using them in a project that had 64 bit platform target selected. Try going to project settings and changing platform target on Build tab to x86.

Comment: No, you exception thrown earlier at connection.Open(). But this exeption thrown after a successfull connection.Open() at cmd.ExecuteReader().